# How to set app name for custom keyboard in Language and input settings screen?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have created a custom keyboard application using Android AOSP source code. While selecting keyboard applications, its name is shown as English(Country Name) + our app name.Actually I need only the App name. Thanks in advance